# Screen Width Issue when using different browsers on Hand Held/Smart Devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, smartphone

I have made a script in which i am detecting the the mobile browser and when its true then the JS function `getwidth` being called and redirects the visitor to a certain URL on the basis of his device's screen width.
I used basic js method of detection i.e `screen.width` to detect screen width

The problem i am facing is that different screen width is being returning in different browsers.Like I have a tablet (Android 4.0.3) whose actual screen width is 800 PX and when i run my script on it by the default browser then it returns accurate screen width `800px` but when I open it with different browsers then they return different widths like UC Browser is returning 740 PX (`ISSUE 2: also when onload function i tried to return screen width on UC browser then it returns screen width as 0px and after page load when i call the same function again then it returns width=740px`) , when i run script on Opera Mini then it returns width as 441 PX.

Kindly let me know which is the most efficient way to detect the screen width of Hand Held/Smart Devices. So i can make the redirection perfectly on the basis of screen width.

URL to TEST: http://radiations3.aiksite.com/home.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, it sounds to me like you shouldn't use Javascript, but rather use CSS.  Have you looked into [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)?  This is the most cross-browser way to detect the width of a screen and then offer a different style accordingly.

If you're not looking to change styles, but redirect as you say (if you must), then I'd suggest the following code (on behalf of [Andy Langton](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/)):

```
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
```

This is the shorthand which will create two variables, `x` and `y`, which are width and height respectively.  Perhaps this is more like what you're looking for, but I'd first suggest checking out media queries and make sure what you're looking to do can't be done with CSS.  There's no guarantee that Javascript is enabled in any browser.

Comment: +1 for media queries! Many mobile devices don't use JavaScript (or have it turned of by default). With the number of variations of devices in existence today, most developers now consider it bad practice to try and cater to specific platforms with JS sniffing. There could be 100 screen sizes out there, who knows? Rather try researching "responsive web design" if you're interested in how to accomplish a mobile compatible site without JavaScript (or at least not dependent on JavaScript being enabled). The idea is to adjust your page using CSS media queries to fit any screen size.

Comment: @soft genic: Did this answer your question at all?

Comment: @cereallarceny I used media query and they are also getting the same screen size that is being returned by javascripting which  waswrong as it depended on the browser size not the actual screen size.

Comment: @softgenic: Correct, if you're looking for the screen's size then media queries won't help you seeing as CSS doesn't have that amount of control. If you're looking to get the browser size and throw layouts around according to that, then media queries are definitely the way to go.  Perhaps you should review your question because it sounds like you're looking for media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried that using jQuery and

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

I never had any trouble using these.